# How to use includes() or indexOf() in vuetify?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am having problem with this piece of code in vuetify:

```
<template>
   ..... {{ countf(options[1], options[2], options[3], options[4], options[5]) }} ......
</template>


<script lang="ts">
export default Vue.extend({

data () {
  return {
    count: 1,
    str: ''
  }
},
   methods: {
      countf(a: any, b: any, c: any, d: any, e: any) {

      this.str = a.title;

        if (this.str.indexOf("Lapel") > -1) {
          this.count++;
        }
        return "Count = " + this.count;
      }
   }
 })
</script>
```

I want to show `Count = 2` in the webpage but whenever I navigate to this page, the page hangs. Can anyone help.

Comment: That is because you are entering a recursion: every time the DOM is repainted, the `countf()` function is invoked, which causes `this.count++` to be executed. This changes the DOM and forces another repaint, and so on and so forth.

Comment: So how can I solve this?

Comment: Create a new variable in the `data` object called `countString` and put the `countf` logic inside the Vue `beforMount` lifecycle method and update `countString` value

Answer (score 0):

To further elabourate on my comment: the reason why your browser freezes is because the way your app is structured causes it to enter infinite recursion once any rendering is attempted:

1. When rendering the DOM, the component's `countf()` method is invoked
2. The method increments `this.count` and also returns a string that is not the same as before
3. This causes the DOM to change, triggering re-rendering, thereby going back to step 1, until the browser runs out of memory

If your logic is only supposed to run once, you can either invoke it in the `created` or `mounted` lifecycle hook, and store the output in a string that is printed in the DOM. In that sense, you are ensuring that there is a **one-way data flow**.

An example below illustrates a possible fix. It is not sure where `options` is coming from, so you might need to make some adjustments:

```
<template>
  ..... {{ countOutput }} ......
</template>

<script lang="ts">
export default Vue.extend({
  data () {
    return {
      count: 1,
      countOutput: '',
      str: ''
    }
  },
  mounted(): {
    this.countOutput = this.countf(this.options[1], this.options[2], this.options[3], this.options[4], this.options[5]);
  },
  methods: {
    countf(a: any, b: any, c: any, d: any, e: any) {

      this.str = a.title;

     if (this.str.indexOf("Lapel") > -1) {
       this.count++;
     }

     return "Count = " + this.count;
    }
  }
})
</script>
```